# Create a Eloquent relationship between a parent table and a lookup table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, orm

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I'm slowly building a complex website, and I've come across a relationship between two of my tables that I cannot immediately figure out how to map together with Eloquent. Here is the relevant schema:

```
table `missions`
mission_id (PK) | name           | launch_site_id (FK)
------------------------------------------------------
1              | someMission    | 1
2              | anotherMission | 3
3              | moreMissions   | 1

table `launch_sites`
launch_site_id (PK) | name   | location
------------------------------------------------------
1                  | Kwaj    | <some coordinate>
2                  | Florida | <some coordinate>
3                  | Russia  | <some coordinate>
```

As you can see, the table `launch_sites` is a lookup table for `missions`, and each mission has a single launch site (guaranteed).

I tried representing this with a `hasOne` & `belongsTo` relationship in Eloquent ORM:

```
class Mission extends Eloquent {
    public function launchSite() {
        return $this->hasOne('LaunchSite');
    }
}

class LaunchSite extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'launch_sites';

    public function mission() {
        return $this->belongsTo('mission');
    }
}
```

However, I quickly realized this would not work as a launch site does not "belong to" a mission. With this relationship, I get the error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'launch_sites.mission_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `launch_sites` where `launch_sites`.`mission_id` = 3 limit 1)

**What relationship setup in Eloquent do I want so I can correctly query and fetch the launch site from a mission like so?**

```
Mission::{{Some Query}}->with('launchSite');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip your relationships around. `Mission` belongs to `LaunchSite` not the other way around.

```
class Mission extends Eloquent {
    public function launchSite() {
        return $this->belongsTo('LaunchSite');
    }
}

class LaunchSite extends Eloquent {
    public function mission() {
        return $this->hasOne('mission');
    }
}
```

By the way you shouldn't need to specify the table name of `LaunchSite`. `launch_sites` is following the convention.